# Remove text on task popup

Tags: sharepoint-online, tasks

With a workflow added to a document, is it possible to remove the text "This workflow task applies to " on the task popup?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove text using css...

Open notepad. Copy this css code..

.ms-informationbar {

display: none;

}

Save file and upload in shared Document.

Add content editor webpart belove Default New Form in Task Popup..
Open Edit Webpart Property. Give full path of that css file. Set Zone Index 2 in Layout and apply..

I hope it will help you..